# How to disable screen locking after sleep on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, sleep

When the computer enters sleep it locks itself and I would like to avoid that. (Ubuntu 9.10)

**Please don't upvote answers that don't work!**

Answer (score 11):

Try:

> Go System > Preferences > Screensaver
>   and uncheck the box that says lock
>   when screensaver is active.

Else

```
gconftool-2 --type boolean -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock_on_blank_screen false
gconftool-2 --type boolean -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock_use_screensaver_settings false
```

If these 2 don't work then

> Open the terminal, and type gconf-editor
>   In the window that comes up
>   go to apps > gnome-power-manager >
>   lock On the right, UNCHECK suspend and
>   hibernate and make sure that the
>   use_screensaver_settings is CHECKED

or -

```
In your terminal type sudo gedit /etc/default/acpi-support
Go to the line that says LOCK_SCREEN=true and put a # in front of it.
```

Close, save and try it out.

All solutions via [UbuntuForums](http://www.uluga.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1310646)

Comment: None of these worked...

Comment: If you look at the seconds page of thread you linked, you will see that it didn't for the OP either...

Comment: Indeed there is a bug filed for that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/255228 if you have an account on launchpad I would suggest you mark the bug as "affects me too" as this gives a chance to be noticed first.

Comment: What's with the downvotes ? You asked for a way, I provided alternatives. If it doesn't work, go file a bug. If I did something wrong put a comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the answer below worked better than any of your alternatives, so I am tempted to downvote just to promote that answer.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the screen lock on suspend you must open a gconf-editor and disable the following options:

> /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock_on_hibernate
>   = false
>
> /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock_on_suspend
>   = false
>
> /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock_on_blank_screen
>   = false

However with this settings when you press the suspend butto you get no screensaver at all and therefore no visible feedback until the laptop is switched off. I solved this second problem by creating a `/etc/acpi/suspend.d/06-gnome-screensaver.sh` script which starts the gnome-screensaver at the beginning of the sleep sequence. Now I have screensaver on suspend but no screen lock dialog on resume.

It would be nice if gnome-power-manager would rename the current lock_on_* options to screensaver_on_* and add a new lock_screen option to decide if locking the screen or simply activating a screensaver.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04, does not work

Answer (score 0):

MoarningSun got it partially working:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/255228

Credit to mac for finding the launchpad bug report, and cleaning it up some.

Comment: See MoarningSun's update. It's pretty unreliable.

Comment: That's why I said partially.  At least he found out part of what wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

What works in 11.04 is to use

```
gconftool-2 --type boolean -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/suspend false
```

you can also replace `suspend` with `hibernate` or `blank_screen` if you wish.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04, does not work